# Why isn't my image displaying when binding the source?

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2

So I have my component which has a table in it. And I want to display an image as a `<td>`. However when I try to bind the path to the image it doesnt show up.

When hardcoding the path it works, it displays the gif just fine

```
<img
src="../assets/banners/01e0a857-95eb-469e-8c86-59a061f32093.gif"
alt=""
style="width: 200px; height: auto"/>
```

And it shows up like this when I inspect it in the browser, it changes the path for some reason.

```
<td><img src="/img/01e0a857-95eb-469e-8c86-59a061f32093.cda90135.gif" alt="" style="width: 200px; height: auto;"></td>
```

But when binding like I do in the example below, it shows up like this when I inspect it in the browser

```
<td><img src="../assets/banners/01e0a857-95eb-469e-8c86-59a061f32093.gif" alt="" style="width: 200px; height: auto;"></td>
```

As you can see, the path points to the correct folder, just like when I hardcoded it, but it doesn't work.

```
   <tbody class="text-gray-00">
   <tr v-for="item in this.items" :key="item.id">
      <td class="w-1/3 text-left py-3 px-4">{{ item.itemName }}</td>
      <td>
         <img
            :src="'../assets/banners/' + item.bannerName + '.gif'"
            alt=""
            style="width: 200px; height: auto"
            />
      </td>
      <td class="text-left py-3 px-4">
         <a class="hover:text-blue-500" href="tel:622322662">622322662</a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-left py-3 px-4">
         <a class="hover:text-blue-500" href="mailto:jonsmith@mail.com"
            >jonsmith@mail.com</a
            >
      </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using relative path like

```
:src="require(`@/assets/banners/${item.bannerName}.gif`)"
```

provided your assets folder should be inside src folder

Comment: The goal is to be able to use the `item.bannerName`, so it would be.. "Path to image" + `item.bannerName`, I only used a hardcoded value to test that it actually finds the image.

Comment: Pls check the edited answer and see if that works!

Comment: Now it won't even render the item

Comment: earlier it used to?

Comment: Yeah, it did generate items before doing that, it just didn't show an image